# Server Response: undefined even if I have the data in the view

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have this connection with ajax, I put a print in the formulario result and in the python in the bash I get the result from the select like this:

```
 [{"pk": 1, "model": "pagoproveedores.test", "fields": {"just_a_test": "google"}}]
```

the problem is that when I want show it in the template it send me Server Response: undefined. Looks like I'm not getting the response from the view, I know I have the data that I need.

view.py

```
def ajax(request):
    print 'inside ajax'
    if request.POST.has_key('client_response'):
        print 'inside if'
        x = request.POST['client_response']
        y = test.objects.filter(just_a_test=x)
        formulario = serializers.serialize('json', y)
        return HttpResponse(formulario, mimetype="application/json")
    else:
        return render_to_response('ajaxexample.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Ajax.html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var input_string = $("#forminput").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajaxexample_json",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                client_response: input_string,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            success: function (json) {
                $('#result').append('Server Response: ' + json.server_response);
            },
             error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What is `json` variable value in response?

Comment: Maybe try using a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) to be able to really see what Django is returning? I think it would make your debugging process much easier.

Comment: I use the tools and I the response that I get it  [{"pk": 1, "model": "pagoproveedores.test", "fields": {"just_a_test": "google"}}]

Answer (score 0):

Instead

```
return HttpResponse(formulario, mimetype="application/json")
```

do

```
return HttpResponse(formulario, content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

I Fix it using this code and same view, ;)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button").click(function () {
         var input_string = $("#forminput").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajaxexample_json",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                client_response: input_string,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },

                 success: function (json) {
                var jsonResponse = eval(json);
                $.each(jsonResponse, function(index, element){
                        alert(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse));
                     $('#resultTables').append('<tr><td  align="center">'+jsonResponse[0]["pk"]+'</td> <td align="center">'+jsonResponse[0]["fields"]["nombre_miembro_1"]+'</td> <td align="center"></td></tr>');

            }); ;
                 },
             error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                }
           });
            return false;
        });
    });
```